# How to show the actionSheet originating from UiButton

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a uiButton and i want to show a action sheet originating from it.
This is my code for close button,

```
+ (void)addLeftButton:(UINavigationItem *)navItem withTarget:(id) navTarget
{
    UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [fixedSpace setWidth:-5];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"];

    UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [closeButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width,   buttonImage.size.height);

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:closeButton];

    [closeButton addTarget:navTarget action:@selector(didSelectCloseButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixedSpace,aBarButtonItem,nil]];
}
```

This IBAction for the close button,

(IBAction)didSelectCloseButton:(id)sender
{

```
if([self->_customer getCheckInDraft])
{
    [self showActionSheet:sender];
}
```

and in showActionSheet I have this code,

```
(void) showActionSheet:(id)sender

{

         if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                [self->_actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

}
```

//Here the showFromBarButtonItem gets the sender as uiButton but it crashes.on clicking the Close button the app crashes.

Comment: Thanks in advance...

Comment: What are you getting in console on crash? Error? Also why are you not using UIActionSheet

Comment: I was getting : "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error message on crash. To show the action sheet i was using 'showFromBarButtonItem' but the button i was using was not a barButtonItem.so it was throwing an error. i should have used 'showFromRect' insted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is action sheet code.

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {

    /* Dismiss keyboard*/

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"What ever you want to ask?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete it" otherButtonTitles:@"Copy", @"Duplicate", nil]; //Change the options that you want to display as per your requirement.

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // In this case the device is an iPad.
        [actionSheet showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        // In this case the device is an iPhone/iPod Touch.
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }

}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheet method implementation

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

  NSLog(@"Index = %d - Title = %@", buttonIndex, [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
   NSLog(@"Action sheet did dismiss");
 }


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
   NSLog(@"Action sheet will dismiss");
}
```

/* UPDATE */

Above is deprecated in iOS 8.3 and above so you could use below UIAlertController.

Also if your keyboard is open while user tap on button then the keyboard dismiss automatically and let the UIAlertController show options.

```
UIAlertController *alertController;
    UIAlertAction *destroyAction;
    UIAlertAction *otherAction;

    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                          message:nil
                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    destroyAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Remove All Data"
                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                               // do destructive stuff here
                                           }];
    otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Blah"
                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                             // do something here
                                         }];
    // note: you can control the order buttons are shown, unlike UIActionSheet
    [alertController addAction:destroyAction];
    [alertController addAction:otherAction];
    [alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                                     popoverPresentationController];

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    popPresenter.sourceView = btn;
    popPresenter.sourceRect = [btn bounds];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: it looks perfect when the keyboard is not open in simulator but when the software keyboard is toggled on for simulator the action sheet is shown in different way.

Comment: @Nikhil : I have updated the code with latest method (UIAlertController) and tried on a demo so its working.

Comment: I have solved the keyboard issue by dissmissing the keybaord on the button click. So the action sheet is shown properly as now keybaord exists.Next time i will try UIAlertController instead of ActionSheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
UIAlertAction *action1;
UIAlertAction *actionCancel;

action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"action1"                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];                                         
actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:nil];

UIAlertController *alertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

alertView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover; // for iPad

[alertView addAction:action1];
[alertView addAction:actionCancel];

if (viewSourse) { // Here your button 

    alertView.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = viewSourse;
    alertView.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect =  CGRectMake(viewSourse.frame.size.width/2, viewSourse.frame.size.height/2, 0, 0);
}

 [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
```